# Blender error: QuadRemesher doesn't work on my sculpting

Tags: python, add-on, error, sculpt, remesh

This is the first time for me using this addon. Every time I try to remesh my sculpting this error appears on the screen:

[image]

[image]

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\quad_remesher_1_2\qr_operators.py", line 745, in modal
    doRemeshing_Finish(self, context)
  File "C:\Users\Giuseppe\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.1\scripts\addons\quad_remesher_1_2\qr_operators.py", line 636, in doRemeshing_Finish
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode=current_mode)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Context missing active object

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

I tried to use the addon on another object (the Suzanne mesh) and seems it works in that case, but not in my scupt.

Comment: The error is `Context missing active object`. This means that you probably havent clicked on the object you need to quadremesh - or you havent selected it correctly. can you provide a gif of you trying to remesh?

Comment: Ok, I added a gif. As I said, I also tried this with the Suzanne mesh and it worked

Comment: I've seen the gif and honestly now have no clue what's gone wrong. You are doing everything properly to my understanding and as youve said, done it and had it work with suzanne. I haven't used quadRemesh personally though so this is about the extent of the help I can give

Comment: According to the QuadRemesher site, supported versions are "from Blender 2.8 to the newest version of Blender (verified with 2.93 LTS and 3.0)", so try it with 3.0. If that doesn't work you should probably [contact](https://exoside.com/company/contact/) the author, but note that contacting is currently closed until the 24th.

Comment: Thank you for the advices. I'm currently using the 3.1.0 version of Blender and I tried this addon on other meshes and it seems to work. Can't figure out what is wrong with this blendfile

Comment: I tryed to append the sculpting mesh to a new blendfile and remeshed it there. It worked! So the problem was actually the blendfile somehow

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this problem, I have also faced this problem. The solution is that you must first select the collection that is checked by the "selectable" icon. Because quad remesh creates a new object inside the selected collection after remeshing.